# Shrink or grow a tensor away from the origin in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

I have a batch x ndim tensor.

I want to add noise to each observation that pushes it either toward or away from the origin without flipping any of the signs.

Can anyone recommend a good approach?

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you are trying to achieve here, but if you want to actually shift values in a tensor, you might want to look at [`torch.roll`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.1.0/torch.html#torch.roll)